# Strapi v4 and tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, strapi

I have created a `Strapi` v4 [plugin](https://strapi.io/plugin-resources) but I don't want to use [Strapi design system](https://design-system.strapi.io/) for my UI (I have create other plugins with Strapi design system]). I want to use [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/).

I have created `tailwind.config.js` and `styles.css` following [installation docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and import them in `/plugins/[plugin-folder]/admin/src/index.js` of my plugin without any success.

Also tried add `tailwindcss` in `/src/admin/webpack.config.js` at `config.plugins` without success again.

Any suggestion? Someone has done it?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it is not something I have done.  But as awesome Tailwind is. I t is not recommended when building plugins for Strapi, especially if you want to list it in the [Strapi Marketplace](https://market.strapi.io/)

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but when creating plugins for Strapi it is highly recommended to use the Design System and any additional custom styling you can add via Styled Components.

But there is also this you can try.  Which may work for you.  [Tailwind Styled Components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-styled-components)